# Where can I find Bobby Fischer's debut game?

Tags: chess

Once I saw the game in an encyclopedia, and I remember being impressed.  Now, I'd like to find it again.  Is there some inventory of famous games I can find it in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you're talking about the [Game of the Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_of_the_Century_%28chess%29), in which 13-year-old Bobby Fischer beat IM (International Master) Donald Byrne, winning a brilliancy prize in the process.

This was of course not Bobby Fischer's "debut" game in that he had played plenty of other tournament games before this; in fact, he [won the United States Junior Chess Championship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Fischer#Young_champion) almost a year beforehand.  However, this is the "earliest" game most people think of when they hear "Bobby Fischer."

[image: Game of the Century]
*13-year-old Bobby Fischer plays 17... Be6!!, sacrificing his queen*

---

As for an inventory of famous games:  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_games) has a list.  Chessmaster also comes with a list of famous games annotated by Grandmasters.

Comment: The Wikipedia page has an annotated PGN.  The pressure from Fischer is enormous!